# In IDFT, can x[n] be reproduced if DFT is ranging from -1pi to 1pi?

Tags: fourier-transform

In short, I can reproduce the original x[n] from DFT via IDFT. However this happens only when I take samples DFT from 0 to 2pi. When DFT is ranging from -1pi to 1pi, the reproduced x[n] is not correct.

I wonder if I do something wrong with the code or it's the fact. Following are 5 steps of my codes in Python.

1. Generate a signal

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

n = np.arange(0, 100)

a1 = 3
a2 = 1
a3 = 0.2

f1 = 1/25
f2 = 1/9
f3 = 1/4

phi1 = 1/2*pi  # 90 degress
phi2 = 1/6*pi  # 30 degrees
phi3 = 1*pi  # 180 degrees

sig1 = a1*np.sin(2*pi*f1*n + phi1)
sig2 = a2*np.sin(2*pi*f2*n + phi2)
sig3 = a3*np.sin(2*pi*f3*n + phi3)

x = (sig1 + sig2 + sig3)
```

[Picture of x[n]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCthx.png)

2. Function to calculate DFT from time domain signal

$X(\omega_k)=X(k)=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x_n \cdot e^{-j\frac{2\pi}{N}kn}$

```py
def dft(omega: float, x: np.ndarray) -> complex:
    """Calculate complex number of input omega, given a time domain x

    Args:
        omega (float): in pi
        x (np.ndarray): signal in time domain

    Returns:
        complex: information of omega in x
    """
    n = np.arange(0, len(x))
    sinusoid = np.e**(-1j*omega*pi*n)
    result = np.dot(x, sinusoid)
    return result
```

3. Omega ranging from -1pi to 1pi, length equals length of x[n]

```py
K = len(x) # length of DFT
omegas = np.linspace(-1, 1, K + 1)  # ranging from -1pi to 1pi
omegas = omegas[:-1]  # remove the last redundant element
X = [dft(omega, x) for omega in omegas]  # DFT
```

4. Function to calculate IDFT

$x(n)=\frac{1}{K}\sum_{k=0}^{K-1}X_k \cdot e^{j\frac{2\pi}{K}kn}$

```py
def idft(n: int, X: list) -> float:
    """Inverse DFT: calcuate time domain from frequency domain

    Args:
        n (int): index of time
        X (list): frequency domain

    Returns:
        float: magnitude of the signal at time n
    """
    k = np.arange(0, len(X))
    sinusoid = np.e**(1j*2*pi/len(X)*k*n)
    result = np.dot(X, sinusoid) / len(X)
    return result
```

5. Reproduce x[n]

```
time_idx = np.arange(0, 100, 1)
x_repro = [idft(n, X) for n in time_idx]
x_repro = [x.real for x in x_repro]
x_repro = pd.Series(x_repro, index=time_idx)
```

[Picture of reproduced x[n]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z492z.png)

Comment: First: in your forward DFT, the "sinusoid" seems to lack $2\pi/N*k$ term. Second: you should apply fftshift() (circular shift) to your DFT samples in $[-\pi,\pi)$ before sending them to a conventional IDFT which excpects its input DFT samples to be in $[0, 2\pi)$.

Comment: This is a really tortured implementation. Note that the definition of DFT and IDFT contains no $\omega$. Time and frequency are represented as integers and that is what your code should be doing as well. Why do you think that $[-\pi, \pi)$ should give the same result? It's different ordering so it represent a frequency shift. That will not give you the same IDFT result. Why should it ? Finally, there are is a very good DFT implementations for Python build-in (e.g. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/fft.html). Why do you want to write your own?

Comment: Hi @Hilmar,
First, I assume the "amount of information" contained in DFT in [0, 2) is the same as in [−,). So I thought both should be able to reproduce x[n]. Thank you very much for confirming that it's not the case. I understand now that we should apply frequency shift to bring [−,) back to [0, 2), in order to reproduce x[n].

Second, I'm aware that numpy and scipy has implementation of DFT and IDFT already. This self-implementation is just for learning purpose. I'm learning DFT so tried to implement the theory in code :)

Comment: Hi @Fat32, so if I understand correctly, IDFT only works with samples in [0,2), everything different should be shifted back to [0,2) in order to reproduce x[n]. Is it right?

Comment: Hi! yes that's right. By DFT and IDFT, I mean as the conventional theory and implementations (including Matlab, FFTW, etc. follows that)